# Creating music player from spotify library c#

Tags: c#, spotify

I am currently trying to create a Music player in C#
I want my app to be able to start and pause music from Spotify, get access to the user's Playlist, and the Spotify song list.
For that, I will obviously need to create a "connect with Spotify button" but I have currently no clues how to do that because the Spotify library isn't well documented
If one of you could help me that would be great
Thanks

Comment: This way too broad for SO!

Comment: It's a commercial system, so I doubt that there is any public documentation

Answer (score 3):

All of this can be done with the [Spotify Web API](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/quick-start/).

1. In order to "start and pause music from Spotify", use the `PUT` [`/me/player/play` endpoint](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/player/start-a-users-playback/)
2. To "get access to the user's playlist", use the `GET` [`/users/{user_id}/playlists` endpoint](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/playlists/get-list-users-playlists/)
3. To get the "Spotify song list", use the `GET` [`/playlists/{playlist_id}` endpoint](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/playlists/get-playlist/) for a specific playlist.

In terms of documentation, learn [how to setup your app](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/app-settings/), [set up authorization](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/), and [work with playlists](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/working-with-playlists/).

There is also a [list of libraries that are built on top of Spotify](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/libraries/#libraries) (even a couple `.NET` ones). The libraries often times [have getting started tutorials](https://johnnycrazy.github.io/SpotifyAPI-NET/web/getting_started.html#first-steps) for each language to help get up and running quickly. Alternatively, there looks to be a [couple](https://hendrikbulens.com/2015/01/07/c-and-the-spotify-web-api-part-i/) [tutorials](https://hendrikbulens.com/2015/01/07/c-and-the-spotify-web-api-part-ii/) out there specifically for c#.

Comment: How do they detect if you are simulating plays?